# Mongodb aggregation for month count based on date or timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**This is my mongodb structure, I need help for aggregation**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f7c2b6ee63ba648209754f1"
    },
    "duration": 23,
    "country": "India",
    "countryCode": "IN",   
    "city": "tamilnadu
    "date": "10/06/2020",
    "timeStamp": "2020-10-06T08:31:42.768Z",
    "__v": 0
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f7c2b7ce63ba648209754f2"
    },
   
    "duration": 12,
    "country": "India",
    "countryCode": "IN", 
    "date": "10/06/2020",  
    "timeStamp": "2020-10-06T08:31:56.438Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I need help for aggregation for sort by month

**The output I need like the count for month and name of the month based on date or timestamp**

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "October-2020": 489
        },
       data:{
"august-2020":12
}

    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

- `$addFields` to convert string date to ISO Date using `$toDate`, you can skip this stage if you have already ISO date format
- `$group` by month and year

  - get month using `$month` form `timeStamp` and convert to string format from array of months using `$let`
  - get year using `$year` from `timeStamp` and convert to string format using `$toString` because `$concat` only concats string
  - `$concat` concat month and year in single string
- get count of grouped documents using `$sum`
- `$project` to show data field and convert result in object format using `$arrayToObject`

```
let months = ["", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { timeStamp: { $toDate: "$timeStamp" } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $concat: [
          {
            $let: {
              vars: { monthsInString: months },
              in: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$monthsInString", { $month: "$timeStamp" }] }
            }
          },
          "-",
          { $toString: { $year: "$timeStamp" } }
        ]
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [{ k: "$_id", v: "$count" }]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ItKYHr3rrsL)

Comment: ok bro....but how can i store timestamp as  "timeStamp": ISODate("2020-10-06T08:31:56.438Z") like this..

Comment: Yes its better, because $month and $year operator will not work in string date it requires ISO date. just save `new Date()` when you save document.

Comment: it is not storing as ISODate(), instead it storing as Thu Oct 22 2020 14:49:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: I thought you are using nodejs, i just check you are using pymongo, i don't know python, i think you will get in stack overflow related this, and i am just adding convertor in my answer, it will work in current date format.

Comment: So new Date() should work, i don't know from where and how you are adding document in collection. make sure you are using new Date() from server side, not frontend side.

Comment: @Naren Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask